# Disable Unsecure WebSocket calls for Node-RED on IBM Bluemix

Tags: node.js, websocket, ibm-cloud, node-red

We have Node-RED application which defined web socket in nodes. Clients able to connect to Node-RED with both WS and WSS. We wanted to block connection if start from `WS:` and only allow `WSS` . `Ex : wss://host.mybluemix.net/test`

Please let us know how to block it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this is currently possible as all SSL/TLS termination is done in the Bluemix Proxy server. All traffic to the actual app comes in as plain HTTP/WS.

Comment: Yes. It seems that you correct. I upvoted your answer. But is there any other way to disable ws connection in NodeRED. I have blocked HTTP by using header. But do not know any method to block WS connections.